# convert gdcm_image to .NET bitmap fail

Tags: c#, gdcm

Hi am trying to get bitmap to display from  DICOM file , but when try to create bitmap from the buffer I get Parameter is not valid for the Bitmap constructor call. I use the following code

```
gdcm.ImageReader reader = new gdcm.ImageReader();
reader.SetFileName(_dicomFilePath);
if (reader.Read())
{
    var image = reader.GetImage();
    if (image != null)
    {
        byte[] imageByteArray = new byte[image.GetBufferLength()];
        if (image.GetBuffer(imageByteArray))
        {
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
            stream.Write(imageByteArray, 0, imageByteArray.Length);
            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(stream);
            CurrentFrameDataGDCM = Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(
                    bmp.GetHbitmap(),
                    IntPtr.Zero,
                    Int32Rect.Empty,
                    BitmapSizeOptions.FromWidthAndHeight((int)image.GetRows(), (int)image.GetColumns()));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to add the specific error message along with the stack trace so we know which parameter is having the issue.

Comment: @SteveMitcham just get error from at System.Drawing.Bitmap..ctor(Stream stream)

Comment: What is the type of the return value for `reader.GetImage()`?  I suspect that it is not the same binary format as a .NET `Bitmap` so it can be deserialized into the Bitmap object.

Comment: yes not the same that's why I get the buffer from it to display it's gdcm_image

Comment: Right, the Stream constructor is only useful for a stream that is in a supported format.  Unless that image object has a direct conversion to a .NET Bitmap in the API somewhere, you'll have to use the empty constructor and roll your own converter.  I'm not familiar with the library that you are using. Here's the link to the types of bitmap formats that are directly supported. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/at62haz6(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: did you figure something out @AMH , I have the same problem